# Dependency Injection of entities in DBContext of EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, dbcontext, dbset

I am new to EF.

Is it possible to inject entities in an EF context?

Taking the case from Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

Let's say, I have different implementations of blog.  When it comes to properties that require persistence, they are the same and implement `IBlog` interface to reflect that.
How should I define `BloggingContext` to work with any of the blogs?  I cannot use `IBlog`.  `DBSet` would not accept an interface as a generic reference type to be used as entity type.

Do I have do define a base abstract class for my blogs in order to inject them in EF context?  Is this the only way?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve by injecting the class in the DbContext? Normally the DbSet maps to a physical table in the database. Are all IBlog implementations stored in the same table? If that's the case, check out this Table Per Hierarchy article: https://entityframework.net/tph

Comment: @BrunoFarias, as I stated above, for persistence purposes all IBlog implementations would map to the same table.  I am not sure how the suggested article answers my question.  When I am reading blogs in a context, I care only about the data, which is mapped the same way for all implementations.  But when it comes to behaviors (implementation of methods), and other non-persistent properties, these implementations are different, and I need to be able to inject them in contexts.  Also, consider unit testing.  How could I mock the entities on which my entity-under-test depends without injection?